# Kafka Stream Punctuator accessing local store data while rebuilding it

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have the feeling a punctuator is able to access local store data while Java KafkaStreams library is rebuilding it replaying items in the changelog topic

Let's describe which is our scenario: I have a KafkaStreams application A (written in Java) in which we are consuming from one topic "incoming-topic" and we are putting some objects into a local store using as key a timestamp plus some unique id, something like:

key -> 201906122345_ds243132eddsfs
value -> object

Then we have a punctuator reading any minute from this store retrieving a range of items from "" to now expressed as yyyymmddhhMM (so 201906122345). We wanted to process those data just once. They are read, removed from the store and forwarded on another topic "intermediate-topic" where they are consumed and processed by another processor.
We noticed that when we add nodes to the application A, or when Kafka is rebalancing partitions among nodes, we are reprocessing old entries. My guess is that the punctuator is accessing the local store while the KafkaStreams library is rebuilding it. I was able to find few of this cases only when rebuilding local store.

Question: is this an expected behavior? Am I using local stores in a wrong way? Can I configure somehow a different behavior having the punctuator not working while rebuilding the local store?

Answer (score 0):

KafkaStreams does not call `Punctuators` while stores are recreated. However, KafkaStreams provide at-least-processing semantics by default, and thus, if an error occurs and partitions are rebalanced, some data may be re-processed.

For regular rebalances, ie, graceful shutdown or if you scale-out, data should actually not be processed twice.

Maybe enabling EOS by setting `processing.guarantees="exactly_once"` does the trick for you. However, if you see duplication during regular/graceful rebalance, you might have an application bug (or there is a bug in KafkaStreams). Hard to tell.